# Connecting Tizen watch with Android phone returns FINDPEER_SERVICE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Hello everyone I've been trying to connect a GearS2 device with an Android phone using the accessory SDK, but every time the service is created and I start the connection the method "onFindPeerAgentResponse" is returning the peer as null and the result integer 1794 which is FINDPEER_SERVICE_NOT_FOUND.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in the config files, the manifest or the service profile.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage this? I would say to take a look at the Samsung example provided for a companion app @ http://developer.samsung.com/gear check the "COMPANION TYPE : HELLO ACCESSORY" It helped me a lot.

Share some code if this example doesn't help find the problem.

Cheers,
Ricardo

Comment: Thanks Ricardo for your answer. Actually, I solved that problem it was the way I was creating the service and also the profile xml file. However, I haven't been able to test the app in a real device(Gear S2). Do you know what the problem could be? I'm thinking is a network issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: All my Tizen development has been with a device, I only use the emulator for visual stuff, so I don't have to be all the time picking the device.. But, the cases I've had with that message has been about, channel ID, package name.. I have to check if over the terminal.